# openGL glGetUniformBlockIndex returning wrong value

Tags: java, opengl

I have a Java `openGL` program which is attempting to update a uniform buffer object. The UBO is never being written to, I can tell from the shaders I am using color output. I was looking and the `glGetUniformBlockIndex` is always returning 0, even though I have a binding specified on my `UBO` in the shaders. I was wondering if anyone could help find what I have done wrong.

Fragment Shader:

```
#version 420
out vec4 outputColor;

layout (std140,binding=1) uniform cameraAndMainLightData{ 
  vec4 camera_position;
  vec4 camera_angle;
  vec4 light_position;
  vec4 light_angle;
};

void main()
{
    if(camera_position==vec4(0f,0f,0f,0f)){
        outputColor=vec4(1f,0f,0f,1f);
    }else{
        outputColor=vec4(0f,1f,0f,1f);
    }
    //outputColor = vec4(camera_position.xyz,1f);
}
```

Vertex Shader:

```
#version 420
in vec4 position;
uniform vec4 trans;

layout (std140,binding=1) uniform cameraAndMainLightData{ 
  vec4 camera_position;
  vec4 camera_angle;
  vec4 light_position;
  vec4 light_angle;
};

void main()
{
    gl_Position = (position + trans)+camera_position;
}
```

`Camera` Class:

```
public class Camera{
    private static Vec4 pos=new Vec4(0);
    private static Vec4 lpos=new Vec4(0);
    private static Vec4 langle=new Vec4(0,1,0,0);
    private static Vec4 lookingAt=new Vec4(0,0,1,0);
    private static int projectionBlockIndex=1,projectionUniformBuffer=0;
    public static void setUpUBO(Shader s){

        projectionUniformBuffer = glGenBuffers();
        glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, projectionUniformBuffer);
        glBufferData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 16 * 4, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

        glBindBufferRange(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, projectionBlockIndex, projectionUniformBuffer, 0, 16 * 4);

        glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0);

        Util.checkGLError();

        int projectionBlock = glGetUniformBlockIndex(s.getID(),"cameraAndMainLightData");
        System.out.println("lbinding: "+projectionBlock);
        glUniformBlockBinding(s.getID(), projectionBlock, projectionBlockIndex);

        Util.checkGLError();


    }

    public static Vec3 getPos(){
        return new Vec3(pos);
    }

    public static void setPos(Vec3 pos){
        Camera.pos = new Vec4(pos,0f);
    }

    public static void update(){

        FloatBuffer sData=ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(64).asFloatBuffer();
        pos.fillBuffer(sData);
        lookingAt.fillBuffer(sData);
        lpos.fillBuffer(sData);
        langle.fillAndFlipBuffer(sData);
        glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, projectionUniformBuffer);
        glBufferSubData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0,sData);
        glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0);
    }
}
```

And the rendering code:

```
@Override
    protected void render(){
        glClearColor(0.5f,0.5f,0.5f,0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        Camera.setPos(new Vec3(Camera.getPos().add(add)));
        Camera.update();
        System.out.print(Camera.getPos().x+", ");
        System.out.print(Camera.getPos().y+", ");
        System.out.println(Camera.getPos().z);
        bear.drawModel();
        Display.sync(5);
    }
```

The line with `Camera.setPos` increments each value of the vector by .05f, and the printing of the values confirms that is does. In the camera code, it shows the same values if printed.

The model is always being drawn in red, which means that the camera position is never being moved.

Comment: You are confusing uniform block _indices_ with uniform block _binding poiints_. It is perfectly OK for your UBO to return index 0.

Comment: I have an [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23203095/whats-gluniformblockbinding-used-for/23203739#23203739) that might clarify this whole system for you. You've gone and explicitly established a binding in your shader code, so the index is not needed for anything.