# glGetUniformBlockIndex returns -1 even with correct block name

Tags: opengl, graphics

For some reason I simply cannot get the SHADER STORAGE BUFFER block index for the buffer in the following shader (which compiled correctly before the buffer).

According to the specification the interface block's name is in this case 'ModelsBlock' and there is no GLSL name, thus the block members are in global scope in the shader.

The models array is also used in two cases so it *should* not be optimised away.

I cant explicitly set the binding point in this case as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23203095/whats-gluniformblockbinding-used-for/23203739#23203739) question.

Shader

```
#version 460 core
uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 camera_view;

in vec3 position;
in vec3 normal;
in vec2 texcoord;

layout(std140) readonly buffer ModelsBlock {
    mat4 models[];
};

in int diffuse_layer_idx;
in int shading_model_id;
in vec3 pbr_scalar_parameters;

out vec3 fNormal;
out vec3 fPosition;
out vec2 fTexcoord;
flat out int fDiffuse_layer_idx;
flat out int fShading_model_id;
flat out vec3 fPbr_scalar_parameters;

void main() {
    gl_Position = projection * camera_view * models[gl_DrawID] * vec4(position, 1.0);

    fNormal = normal;
    fPosition = vec3(models[gl_DrawID] * vec4(position, 1.0));
    #if defined(DIFFUSE_CUBEMAP)
    fPosition = vec3(vec4(position, 1.0));
    #endif
    fTexcoord = texcoord;
    fDiffuse_layer_idx = diffuse_layer_idx;
    fShading_model_id = shading_model_id;
    fPbr_scalar_parameters = pbr_scalar_parameters;
}
```

Neither of these work, all of them just returns -1.

```
const int32_t gl_models_block_idx = glGetUniformBlockIndex(program, "ModelsBlock"); 
const int32_t gl_models_block_idx = glGetUniformBlockIndex(program, "models"); 
const int32_t gl_models_block_idx = glGetUniformBlockIndex(program, "models[]"); 
const int32_t gl_models_block_idx = glGetUniformBlockIndex(program, "models[0]");
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no **uniform** block in your code:

> ```
> layout(std140) readonly buffer ModelsBlock {
>     mat4 models[];
> };
> ```

You just declared an [SSBO](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader_Storage_Buffer_Object) containing your `models` array. The data layout for that is well-defined by the rules of `std140`, so it is toally unclear what you're trying to query here (even if it were an UBO). The array starts at offset 0, and each array is 4 column vectors with 4 floats each, so 64byte per matrix, no additional padding, so that `models[i]` is bound to be at offset `64*i`.

Comment: Hmm, according to this, https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Interface_Block_(GLSL)#Block_buffer_binding, I can query the block index in order to later assign a buffer index to it? I want to change the buffer that is backing the SSBO if it is unclear.

Comment: `glGetUniformBlockIndex` is for _uniform_ buffers only.

Comment: I should use glGetProgramResourceIndex, shouldnt I..?

Comment: For SSBOs, you must use the program introspection [interface query API](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Program_Introspection#Interface_query). Note that in most cases, it is much better to directly specifiy the `binding` in the shader sources itself.

Comment: Yes, but in my case I need each (shader instance) to use a different binding point.

Comment: @Entalpi: Then fix *that*; there is no reason for you to be changing binding points when you could just change what buffer is bound to the correct point. Querying will always be slower than doing it right.

Comment: I am sorry for expressing myself so confused but your are right. I got it all mixed up and ended up doing exactly that, just switching the buffer that are bound to the binding points rather than the opposite.